# Error uploading APK in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, keytool, android-keystore, android-studio-2.2

I recently create my 4th project on `Google Play Developer Console`. Since yesterday i am trying to upload the first project `APK` in Alpha but i am getting this error:

> You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon.
>   You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into
>   the future.

I always generate the keys using `keytool` and developing, generating the `APK` and signing using `Android Stuido`.

I have created my `keystore` with my first project and everithing works ok for that project. Also no problem with the 2nd and the 3rd.

I already try using `-validity 20000` like is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499834/upload-apk-file-to-google-play) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280371/sign-android-apk-with-a-certificate-that-expires-further-in-to-the-future) but i got the same error message.

This is command that i am using to create the key:

```
keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore "my_key_store" -alias "my_alias_key" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

Maybe the error message is wrong. I list the key information and the expires date is right, is valid until

> Fri Jul 03 21:21:22 UYT 2071

Comment: That looks right. Are you sure it was your release apk? The debug APKs usually expire in 365 days.

Comment: Yes, sure, the build type was release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the same command, signed the `APK` in the same way and uploaded using the same browser and it worked fine. 
Seems to be a problem in `Google Play Developer Console`.
Very odd.